# Rails: Invalid single-table inheritance type error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

So, I am working on migrating this php site with an existing database which I cannot change over to Rails. There is a table: `Quotes` with a column named `type`. Whenever I try and create a model of this and set the type, it tells me the following error:

`ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound (Invalid single-table inheritance type: HOME is not a subclass of Quotes)`

I don't understand why it thinks its inheriting because it's not supposed to. My create method looks like this:

```
quote = Quotes.create(
  agent_id: agent.id,
  client_id: client.id,
  type: 'HOME',
  status: 0,
  date_created: DateTime.now 
)
```

If I comment out the type, everything works fine. But with the Type it errors.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I resolved this by setting the models inheritance_column to nil. Active Record Models can inherit from a table through the attribute `:type`, setting the inheritance_column to nil removes that attribute allowing you to have a database column named `type`

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.inheritance_column = nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. I had a column named "type" and it was causing the error.

Answer (score 3):

I hate having potential gotchas deep in the code especially in the intial processes like generating a model. Better to just change the reserved word to something else and free yourself up to take advantage of inheritance column later if the need comes up. A cleaner solution is listed here ->  [rename a database column name using migration](http://karthikrajah.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/how-do-i-rename-a-database-column-using-migration-in-rails/)

It reads;

1. Execute $> rails generate migration ChangeColumnName 
   where, ChangeColumnName is the name of our migration. This can be any name.
2. Now, edit the generated migration file at db/migrate/_change_column_name.rb

   ```
   class ChangeColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
   rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
   end
   end
   ```
3. $> rake db:migrate

You will have to edit controller and view files e.g. if the model name is Product then you will likely edit these files

1. /app/views/products/_form.html.erb
2. /app/views/products/show.html.erb
3. /app/controllers/products_controller.erb
4. /app/views/products/index.html.erb

Comment: While I agree that is the best practice, my problem involved using a Legacy Database in which I didn't have the ability to change things.