# How to choose an inclusive select option for a model in seed data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Dog` model that can have many `tags` and my `Tag` model has the column `type`. For the `type` attribute I can only choose 3 different types:

```
class Tag
 belongs_to :dog
 TYPES = %w(Red Blue Green)

 validates :type, inclusion: { :in => TYPES },
                  presence: true
end
```

In my seed file I have:

```
tags = Tag.create( [ { name: "Red Terrier", type: "Red" } ] )
```

I run the rake command and get the error:

```
rake aborted!
Invalid single-table inheritance type: Red is not a subclass of Tag
```

What's going on here? What's the way to do this and why does it think it's a subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` is a reserved column name that rails uses for polymorphic models. Try renaming your `type` column to `dog_type` and it should work

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions

Answer (score 2):

Do not use ‘type‘ as a column name. It's reserved in Rails. Rename it and it will work

Answer (score 1):

---

You ran in to a bug because of what's going on behind the scenes in Rails. Basically `type` is a field that is used for `ActiveRecord` inheritance, so having a field also named `type` is messing things up

One possible solution: create a new migration, and just use `rename_column` to give the `type` column a different name.

Another possible solution is given here: [Rails: Invalid single-table inheritance type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243367/rails-invalid-single-inheritance), although I don't personally know the implications of doing this.